# Listen to field changes inside a form in dojo

Tags: validation, dojo

When saving a form I deactivate the save button to avoid double submission. Save happens through an Ajax call, so I stay on the same page. I want to re-enable the button only if the form got changed. How can I listen to any field change inside a specific form using Dojo 1.6 dojo.connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 358 of dijit/form/_FormMixin.js the connectChildren function :)
It gives you all the necessary information!
Basically if your children are connected (you could call the function to make sure), you then just have to monitor the form.value